# Why tests sometimes build failed (maven-surefire-plugin)?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, surefire

In Netbeans i wrote my projects using selenium. Sometimes projects build ok, sometimes build falied. I think, the problem is in maven-sunfire-plugins. But why from 48 builds only 3-4 is failed?

In jenkins console I see:

```
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException:
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is        
  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
```

POM file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.com.mycompany.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>selenium-test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://maven-repo.myportal.pl:3080/artifactory/repo</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>http://maven-repo.myportal.pl:3080/artifactory/repo</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>internal</id>
            <name>Archiva Managed Internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven-repo.myportal.pl:3080/archiva/repository/internal</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>selenium-test</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <!--<encoding>Cp1250</encoding> -->
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <!--<encoding>ISO-8859-2</encoding> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Selenium -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.43.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.com.mycompany.selenium.util</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-listener</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.com.mycompany.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-portal</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>weblogic</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TESTS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
            <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!-- -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>2db</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.11</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>listener</name>
                                    <value>pl.com.mycompany.selenium.util.TestNgRunSuiteListener</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                            <systemProperties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>job_name</name>
                                    <value>${project.artifactId}</value>
                                </property>
                            </systemProperties>

                            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>

                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Oddest is it a lot of builds its okey. From 48 builds only 3 throw this and I don't understand why.
Where is error?

Comment: Selenium tests have to be written very carefully otherwise they contain race conditions in which case the tests fail from time to time even if you would then execute it manually on your computer. At least from my experience with selenium.

Comment: You should not use maven-surefire-plugin as a dependency. Furthermore selenium tests are integration tests which should be handled by maven-failsafe-plugin.